# Windows Form delete the drawn ellipse

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

I have created some Ellipses on Windows form

I want that selectable while mouse over and if i select any ellipse it will delete from Window

Here some code for create ellipse in c#

```
public void DrawCircle_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Black, 3); Graphics gr = this.CreateGraphics(); gr.DrawEllipse(pen, 40, 45, 20, 20);
    Pen pen2 = new Pen(Color.Black, 3); Graphics gr1 = this.CreateGraphics(); gr.DrawEllipse(pen2, 30, 25, 38, 20);
    Pen pen3 = new Pen(Color.Black, 3); Graphics gr2 = this.CreateGraphics(); gr.DrawEllipse(pen3, 35, 36, 68, 15);
    Pen pen4 = new Pen(Color.Black, 3); Graphics gr3 = this.CreateGraphics(); gr.DrawEllipse(pen4, 50, 60, 67, 35);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]. If you feel that your question has been edited incorrectly, reject their edit if it has been suggested, and if it has been approved by others anyway, you can roll it back by clicking on the "edited x seconds ago" link, going to the revision that you want, and clicking "rollback".

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```
this.Invalidate();
```

That should clear them....

Either that, or

```
Graphics.Clear();
```

Edit:

Actually, another method be to have a boolean inside of your mouse on hover, and use that to dictate when to draw the elipse/not. As a general note, you should be putting the elipse drawing in an override of onpaint. Right now, currently, if you were to invalidate the screen (either by you, or by Windows), your shapes will disappear. An Example using on paint.

```
bool paint = false;
protected override void OnPaint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    if (paint) 
    {
          Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Black, 3); Graphics gr = this.CreateGraphics(); gr.DrawEllipse(pen, 40, 45, 20, 20);
          Pen pen2 = new Pen(Color.Black, 3); Graphics gr1 = this.CreateGraphics(); gr.DrawEllipse(pen2, 30, 25, 38, 20);
          Pen pen3 = new Pen(Color.Black, 3); Graphics gr2 = this.CreateGraphics(); gr.DrawEllipse(pen3, 35, 36, 68, 15);
          Pen pen4 = new Pen(Color.Black, 3); Graphics gr3 = this.CreateGraphics(); gr.DrawEllipse(pen4, 50, 60, 67, 35);
    }
}
```

I don't remember the specific paramters for it, but in your OnMouseHover (where you want to turn off your elipse)

```
OnMouseHover(){
    ...
    paint = false;
    this.Invalidate(); 
}
```

Comment: Where? I would put them inside of the mousehoverover (when you want to remove the elipses)

Comment: I don't actually think its possible to select them programmatically... I have an alternative

Comment: it gives and Error While OnPaint method override 'no suitable method found to override'...

Comment: hmmm ok. With the onPaint, you are placing that method in your form, right?